# how to programmatically close a eclipse rcp 4 mwindow

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

i create an MWindow at runtime with

```
MWindow window = _modelService.createModelElement(MWindow.class);
window.setWidth(200);
window.setHeight(300);
// add new Window to the application 
// @Inject
// MApplication _application;
_application.getChildren().add(window);
```

than i add a part to it with

```
EModelService windowModelService = window.getContext().get(EModelService.class);
EPartService windowPartService = window.getContext().get(EPartService.class);

// find part if exists
MPart part = windowPartService.findPart("partId");

if (part == null) {
    // create if not exists
    part = windowPartService.createPart("partId");
}


// Required if initial not visible
part.setVisible(true);

// Show the part
MPart newPart = windowPartService.showPart(part, PartState.VISIBLE);
```

but i have no idea how to close or dispose this window after it is no longer used. Mwindow has no close / dispose or exit functions. And if i try to simply remove it from the applications children i get npe.

How to get rid of the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `EPartService.hidePart(MPart)` or `hidePart(MPart, boolean)`.

`hidePart(MPart)` normally just hides the part but if the `removeOnHide` value is set in the part Tags then it is also deleted.

`hidePart(MPart, true)` lets you force the delete regardless of the tags.

Edit:

To close the window call `MWindow.setToBeRendered(false)` the window will remain in the application model but resources etc. will be disposed.

Comment: hidePart(MPart, true) removes the MPart from the window. But i would like to remove or close the window itself. As long as the windows stays active the application can not close.

Comment: You can call 'IWorkbench.close()' to exit the application regardless of open windows.

Comment: Added window close info

Comment: IWorkbench.close() called from within the mwindow closes only this mwindow and not the application?

Comment: according to 
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIWorkbench.html

it should really close all windows. But it does not :(

Comment: This is not the behavior I see in my app, it just closes the app. This is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench` not `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench`.

Comment: You're right. I fired the wrong event and never reached the close.

Comment: and look what i found :)
calling ((Widget) window.getWidget()).dispose(); removes only one window